# Deny access to specfic route in web.xml - Java

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, jboss, web.xml

I have a Java app with a React app embbebed in the same maven project. I want to block specific routes from frontend (eg: examplehost.com/#/dashboard) with web.xml security constraints but I can't.

Now I have an ingress role, assigned to all routes "/*", so if you have this permission, you have access to all the entire app. I want to keep this role, but restricting another specific routes. Is it possible?

security constrant of ingress:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>ROOT</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>INGRESS_ROLE</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <description>Permiso de acceso a la aplicación</description>
        <role-name>INGRESS_ROLE</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

In words of chatGPT: Unfortunately, the security restrictions in the web.xml file are not directly applicable to URL fragments that include the # (hash) character. The URL fragment (everything after the #) is not sent to the server and is therefore not visible on the server side. The part after # is rendered only in the client's browser.

Comment: Can you share what you have and what you want to change it will more relevant ?